# FontAwesome Icons disturbs pixel during transformation

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I am using FontAwesome Icons in my application on a tree structure list. fa-caret-down and fa-caret-right disturbs my pixel like on right to dow it moves content right to 5 pixels during change fa-caret-right to fa-caret-down.

Here is my html code:

```
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
```

CSS:

```css
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  /*font-size: inherit;*/
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.fa-caret-right:before {
  content: "\f0da";
}
.fa-caret-down:before {
  content: "\f0d7";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font Awesome has a fix for this.

**Fixed Width Icons**

> Use fa-fw to set icons at a fixed width. Great to use when different icon widths throw off alignment. Especially useful in things like nav lists & list groups.

[Here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) you can find information on different Font Awesome Features.

```css
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="fa fa-caret-down fa-fw"></span>
        Fruit
        <ul>
            <li>Apple</li>
            <li>Orange</li>
            <li>Apple</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="fa fa-caret-right fa-fw"></span>
        Animals
        <ul>
            <li>Monkey</li>
            <li>Dog</li>
            <li>Cat</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice solution. I was under the impression the `.fa-fw` class was specific to their documentation pages and not a production thing. +1

Comment: Reading these documentations carefully can really be a blessing some time, i had to go to a lot of struggling before i found this little helper class. He he he...

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that Font-Awesome icons are nothing more than simple characters - letters, if you like. The letter 'W' for example is wider than the letter 'I' - equally `.fa-caret-down` is wider than `.fa-caret-right`.

To overcome this problem, one solution to this is to define a specific `width` on your `i` element to stop different icons from influencing this value themselves:

```css
i.fa {
    text-align: center;    /* If you want the icons to appear central. */
    width: 20px;           /* Adjust accordingly. */
}
```

Comment: Just curious what about `1ch`?

Comment: @Paulie_D that's a neat idea but unfortunately it doesn't seem reliable enough. For instance, `1ch` causes text to overlap on the majority of icons, and even `2ch` isn't enough to remove this text overlap from some of the much larger icons (e.g. the credit card ones or `.fa-motorcycle`.